# Creating and Updating GKE cluster via gcloud 302.0.0 fails

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

When creating a new GKE cluster using gcloud with cloud run addon using gcloud `302.0.0`, cluster creation fails.

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 302.0.0

$ gcloud container clusters create CLUSTER_NAME --addons=HttpLoadBalancing,CloudRun --enable-stackdriver-kubernetes
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workaround is to upgrade to `303.0.0` or downgrade to `301.0.0`.

`gcloud components update`

or to a specific version:

`gcloud components update --version=303.0.0`

or following the other upgrading and downgrading instructions: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get#downgrading_cloud_sdk_versions

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I found this Public Issue tracker about same issue

https://issuetracker.google.com/161826147